# Need of SingleThreadPool in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, executor

I have a few questions regarding ExecutorService.

1. In what cases we should use `newSingleThreadExecutor()` than others and **Why**?
2. Can you tell me the **real use case** of having `SnewSingleThreadExecutor()`?
3. If we have a single thread either from (`newSingleThreadExecutor()` or `newFixedThreadPool(1)` or `newCacheThreadPool(1)`) Do we still need to check for Thread Safety?
4. Why do we need `newSingleThreadExecutor()` if we can already create a single thread using `newFixedThreadPool(1)`

Comment: where did you find it?

Comment: Please use the correct capitalization of (standard) Java class and method names to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you don't want tasks to run in parallel because of common data.
2. Swing's Event Dispatch Thread. It is not called executor, but in fact it is, just its `execute` method is called `invokeLater`.
3. It depends on what data you access. If that data can be accessed outside the tasks running on this executor, then yes. It does not depend of how you built your executor.
4. We do not need. I don't know what SingleThreadPool do you mean - there is no such class in Java runtime libarary.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question. Can you please answer on that?

Comment: if you really want to know the difference between newSingleThreadExecutor and newFixedThreadPool(1), look at the source code of both methods. Then ask another question, do not edit this one.